# With git, if I merge a branch and then delete that branch are the individual commits lost?

Tags: git

In the [documentation for git's `merge` command](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html), the result of `git merge topic` is shown as this:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

In this scenario it looks to me that if I were to delete `topic` to keep my branch list tidy, that all record of commits A, B, and C would be lost, leaving only a single commit, H (and presumably deleting all the commit messages from A, B, and C):

```
D---E---F---G---H master
```

Would this indeed be the case, and if so how would I prevent it? E.g:

```
D---E---F---G---A---B---C master
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No.  Everything would still be there.

**Before** deleting topic branch:

```
      A---B---C topic
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

**After** deleting topic branch:

```
      A---B---C
     /         \
D---E---F---G---H master
```

The branch is just a pointer to commit C.  Deleting it doesn't get rid of the commit.

Note that if you haven't merged the topic branch yet, then deleting it will fail unless you use `git branch -D`.  The `git branch -d` command will only delete merged branches, which preserves all the history but gets rid of the branch name.

**Footnote:** You can get the following history by using `git rebase master` from the topic branch, and then fast-forwarding master to topic, and deleting topic.

```
D---E---F---G---A'---B'---C' master
```

Note that while this is *possible* it is probably not *desirable* -- the original commits A, B, and C are lost by rebasing.

Comment: +1 Exactly. The thing to keep in mind is: *In git, a branch is just a name pointing to a commit* (which moves along as you commit new stuff).

Comment: Yes, I realize the actual CHANGES from A, B, and C would be preserved. Are you saying that the commit messages, etc would also stay the same?

Comment: @Ajedi32: "The branch is just a pointer to commit C."  Deleting the branch doesn't change *anything* about the history.  Think about it like pulling sticky notes out of a book -- you lose your place, but the book is still there.

Comment: Great answer, but I would go a little farther and actually suggest that the rebased history you mention *is* desirable provided that A, B, and C have not been pushed to any other repositories. After reading about a [rebase workflow](http://randyfay.com/content/rebase-workflow-git) I've been happily using it ever since in lieu of most merges.

Comment: @MattWinckler: The linked article has a flawed understanding of merge workflows (please read Linus's famous post about branching/merging at random points) and presents arguments with logical errors (merge conflicts happen both with rebase and merge, so rebasing is no easier than merging; bisecting is *worse* with rebase than merge).  The rebase vs. merge question comes up often enough on Stack Overflow, and the answer is a lot more subtle than merely ensuring that A, B, and C are private.  Doing the subject justice would mean going off-topic, but OP is welcome to open another question.

Comment: I agree, it's OT, but thanks for your comments. (In fairness to the article, I understood his argument to be about _where_ conflicts occurred rather than _whether_ they would occur.) I'll have to do more reading on and look for that post you mentioned.

Comment: @MattWinckler: The post I mentioned: http://lwn.net/Articles/328438/ -- The top half is Linus complaining about people abusing rebase, the bottom half is Linus complaining about people abusing merge.